# HTML5 Canvas Growing Circles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I am trying to make it so that, when a user click anywhere on the screen, a circle will appear at the point of clicking, and proceed to grow. I don't want to use jQuery, if possible. I made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8R4/

I think that the error is in the circ() function:

```
function circ(x, y, rad, c){    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = c;
    ctx.stroke();
    function2();
    function function2(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = c;
        ctx.stroke();
        rad+=3;
        if(rad<=canvas.width){
            function2();
        }
    }

}
```

My error seems to be that, instead of showing the circle grow, it is just showing all of the circles stacked up. Ideally, a user would be able to click in two or three places and see multiple circles growing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your fiddle is trying to pull in resource it can't load.

Comment: ? Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you were having is that the code was calling itself in a hard loop - basically just flooding the background with color.

Try wrapping your function2 call in setTimeout like this:

```
if (rad <= canvas.width) {
    setTimeout(function2, 200);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8R4/)

You'll probably want to take a look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), but this should get you going.

Also, this only gets the circles expanding.  Depending on the final effect you want, you may want to keep track of the circles you have started, and iterate/draw them during each animation pass.

**Update**

Heres a version that does a better job drawing the circles overlapping each other and using requestAnimationFrame (webkit version)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ8R4/3/)

**Code**  (just the relevant portions)

```
var circles = [];

function circ(x, y, rad, c) {
    ctx.fillStyle = c;  // <<== Sets the fill color
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    // No need to update context these as we are filling the circle instead
    //ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    //ctx.strokeStyle = c;
    //ctx.stroke();

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();  // <<== Fills the circle with fill color
}

function draw() {
    var newCircles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; ++i) {
        circ(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].radius, circles[i].colour);
        circles[i].radius += 3;
        if (circles[i].radius <= canvas.width) newCircles.push(circles[i]);
    }

    circles = newCircles;
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Comment: It doesn't work exactly as I wanted, but it was more than enough to get me there. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahT - updated answer with additional version that I *think* is more what your looking for.